# i want to implement route like webapi in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am invoking the url "localhost/Student/1" to return the student with id=1. My route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "StudentID",
               url: "Student/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Get}
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SchoolDbEntities db = new SchoolDbEntities();
            return View(db.Students);
        }
        [Route("Student/{id}")]
        [ActionName("Get")]
        public ActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            SchoolDbEntities db = new SchoolDbEntities();
            var student = db.Students.Where(s => s.Id == id);
            return View(student);
        }
    }
```

I configured both route table and use route attributes.
However when i run the application it throws an error:
The resource cannot be found.

how do i implement the same as using webapi.

Comment: Your first route makes no sense - it just means that it matches any route with 1 or 2 segments (or is that really `url: "Student/{id}",`?) And have you implemented attribute routing in your `RouteConfig` file?

Comment: its Student/id. I have edited the route

Comment: In that first route , the id cannot be optional.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i have removed the optional part.

Comment: Also, use the MapRoute() _or_ the [Route()]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use attribute routes in MVC you must register them by calling `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` in your `RouteConfig` class.

Note that the registration order matters. By putting the call to `route.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` before your `routes.MapRoute()` call MVC will look at the attribute routes before the traditional routes. The first matching route wins.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In your controller setup your attribute routing like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("Student")]    
public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SchoolDbEntities db = new SchoolDbEntities();
            return View(db.Students);
        }

        [Route("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            SchoolDbEntities db = new SchoolDbEntities();
            var student = db.Students.Where(s => s.Id == id);
            return View(student);
        }
    }
```

This will match the URL "Student/1".

Comment: I would like to have like "Student/1" instead of "Student/Get/1"